# CMake dependency on defined (preprocessor) header file

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a configuration file setup that defines the correct header files to include for certain components. Later I include that file via the preprocessor token. Unfortunately CMake's dependency scanner completely ignores the header file.

Essentially it comes down to this:

```
#define HEADER_FILE "somefile.h"
#include HEADER_FILE
```

CMake does not add `"somefile.h"` to the list of dependencies for this source file!

How can I get CMake to recognize this dependency correctly?

*(I know that I can do #if 0 blocks and include all the files, but this either includes too many dependencides for other sources, or defeats the whole purpose in the first place -- depending on how you do it)*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add an explicit dependency to a source file by setting the `OBJECT_DEPENDS` property:

```
set_property(SOURCE source.cpp APPEND PROPERTY OBJECT_DEPENDS "somefile.h")
```

You'll have to do this for any source file that includes your configuration file.

Comment: Thanks, this actually helps me in another situation as well (dealing with unsupported source files).

Comment: Dealing with legacy code under CMAKE and ran into this exact situation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest to make the header file generic instead of all the sourcefiles? This is also more common than your approach that I never saw in any production code.

Like this:

```
// meh.hh
#ifndef MEH_HH
#define MEH_HH

#ifdef THIS
# include <this>
#elif defined(THAT)
# include <that>
#else
# error meh
#endif 

#endif // MEH_HH
```

---

```
// main.cc
#include "meh.hh"

int main () {...}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am trying to get away from (it's what I did before). Rather than simply have a define for each header I'd instead have to have a configurable header file for all those headers.

Comment: Why would your approach be superior to the canonical one? Not only CMake will struggle with it, but also IDEs and editors (think of "switch header/source" or "goto file")

Comment: My approach is the one supported by the C preprocessor: Simply set a DEFINE to the name of the file to include. It doesn't involve writing wrapper files, thus less to maintain.

Comment: Mine is certainly supported by the C preprocessor as well ;) Documentation is also maintenance, and I think a handful of wrapper files is better at self-documentation because they enlist available definitions, and it could even made to work by adding the #defines at the top of those wrappers. Your approach means you either need to include the defining header + the header, or to supply the definition directly to the compiler.